# Using PowerShell, set the AD home directory for a user, given the display name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to set the home directory based on a csv file containing a list of usernames.

I imagine there is a combination of get-user, set-user, and foreach commands that give the correct updates. 
Here is the code I am using but I'm unable to make the logical jump to piping this output to a Set-ADUser command which sets the home directory.

```
function ConvertUser($user)
{
    $search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]“”)
    $search.filter = “(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=$user))”
    $results = $search.Findall()

    foreach($result in $results){
         $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
         Write-Output($userEntry.sAMAccountName)
    }
 }

function ConvertUsers
{
     process{
        foreach($user In $_){
            ConvertUser($user)
        }
    }
}

Get-Content ".Users.txt" | ConvertUsers
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but alas I am a Powershell newb.

Edit: I would like to have the output from ConverUsers which is the username and then pipe that to the set-aduser command.  Any time I try and pipe it to set-aduser I either get syntax errors, empty pipe, or the wrong data output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet. It has a `-HomeDirectory` parameter, which obviously allows you to set the user's home directory, and an `-Identity` parameter that specifies which user you are editing. It also has a `-HomeDrive` parameter that specifies the drive letter for their home directory.

```
# 1. Get the user, based on their "display name"
$User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(displayname=Trevor Sullivan))';
# 2. Change the user's home directory and home drive
Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -HomeDirectory \\fileserver\users\trevor -HomeDrive U;
```

[image: Active Directory Users & Computers]

Given the following CSV file contents:

[image: CSV Contents]

The following script should set the home drives:

```
# 1. Import the user data from CSV
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path c:\test\Users.csv;

# 2. For each user ...
foreach ($User in $UserList) {
    # 2a. Get the user's AD account
    $Account = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter ('(&(displayname={0}))' -f $User.DisplayName);
    # 2b. Dynamically declare their home directory path in a String
    $HomeDirectory = '\\fileserver\users\{0}' -f $Account.SamAccountName;
    # 2c. Set their home directory and home drive letter in Active Directory
    Set-ADUser -Identity $Account.SamAccountName -HomeDirectory $HomeDirectory -HomeDrive u;
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  However, all I have is the display name and this command needs the username.

Comment: You can get the user's account information by running `Get-ADUser` with an LDAP filter on the `displayname` Active Directory attribute: `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(displayname=Trevor Sullivan))';`

Comment: So how would I go about setting the home directory using the foreach loop?  I have a csv file containing the list of display names.

Comment: What do the contents of the CSV look like? I have no idea what fields are inside of it.

Comment: Updated answer with example CSV contents (including `displayname`)and foreach loop to set home directory. You can update it to reflect your file server name and share path.

Comment: Thank you Trevor.  Unfortunately my work blocks imgur so I'm unable to see your example screenshots.  I've marked your answer as correct since that is essentially what I was looking to do.

Comment: There is a bug in the example above. The parameter should be -HomeDrive U: (there should be a colon mark instead of a semicolon).