# Set HomeDirectory parameter for users on ADDS 2008 R2 with powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, scripting, active-directory

I'm trying to set "HomeDirectory" parameter to a list of users given a .csv file.  I'm using an modified script created by Trevor Sullivan and listed on the following post:
[Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030086/using-powershell-set-the-ad-home-directory-for-a-user-given-the-display-name/21030149#21030149?newreg=689f2dd1a4aa4a42ad3b957030fb2dab)

This is my script:

```
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\Users2.csv;  
foreach ($User in $UserList)  {

$Account = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName
$Account.HomeDirectory = '\\adminclusterfs\homedir\{0}' -f $Account.SamAccountName;
$Account.homeDrive = "O:"
Set-ADUser -Instance $Account -PassThru
}
```

The script works almost fine... The HomeDirectory and HomeDrive parameters are setting up correctly for each user on the .csv file but, **the folder aren't created on the fileserver.**

when I set these parameters manually, the folder are created as well

Someone has solved this issue?

I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Please don't use links. Instead, copy a minimal but sufficient extract of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the complete script that I made to set HomeDirectory and HomeDrive parameter, create the folder and assign it the access rigths. Thank you to Trevor Sullivan and Sean Kearney for their posts.

```
# Import the user data from CSV
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path c:\scripts\Users2.csv;

# For each user ...
foreach ($User in $UserList) {
# Get the user's AD account
$Account = Get-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName

# Dynamically declare their home directory path in a String
$Account.HomeDirectory = '\\fileserver\homedir\{0}' -f $Account.SamAccountName;
$Account.homeDrive = "O:"

# Set their home directory and home drive letter in Active Directory
Set-ADUser -Instance $Account

# Create the folder on the root of the Homedirectory Share
NEW-ITEM –path $Account.HomeDirectory -type directory -force 

# Set parameters for Access rule
$IdentityReference = 'Domain\' + $Account.SamAccountName
$FileSystemAccessRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::"ContainerInherit","ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"None"
$AccessControl = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]"Allow"

# Build Access Rule from parameters
$AccessRule = NEW-OBJECT System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -argumentlist ($IdentityReference,$FileSystemAccessRights,$InheritanceFlags,$PropagationFlags,$AccessControl)

# Get current Access Rule from Home Folder for User
$HomeFolderACL = GET-ACL $Account.HomeDirectory
$HomeFolderACL.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)

# Set Access rule to the folder
SET-ACL –path $Account.HomeDirectory -AclObject $HomeFolderACL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AD Users and Computers creates the folder for you, if your account has access to. That's a feature of the Users and Computers program running on your computer, not of the AD server itself.

You will have to add code in your script to create the folder.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I found some papers where explain all the process to create the folders and to assign access permissions correctly. [link] https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/04/creating-a-home-drive-with-windows-powershell-part-1/